# Storing the Text Entries of a combo box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a  text box that will retain the last 10 entries entered, similar to the search box in Internet Explorer. The user can click on the dropdown menu to see last 10 entries. The drop down menu is a combo box. I created an Observable collection of strings that is bound to the combo box Itemssource.Below is the code.

**Xaml**

```
<Grid x:Name="TextBox_grid" Margin="0,0,40,0" Width="360" Height="23">
    <ComboBox Name="cb" Margin="0,0,-29,0" Style="{DynamicResource Onyx_Combo}" ItemsSource="{Binding TextEntries, ElementName=TheMainWindow, Mode=OneWay}"  IsEditable="False" Visibility="Visible" />
    <Rectangle Fill="#FF131210" Stroke="Black" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2"/>
    <TextBox Name=UniversalTextBox Margin="0" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontSize="16" Foreground="#FFA0A0A0" TextWrapping="Wrap" PreviewKeyDown="TextBox_PreviewKeyDown"/>
</Grid>
```

**Code**

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{

    private ObservableCollection<string> m_TextEntries = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<string> TextEntries
    {
        get { return m_TextEntries; }
    }
    private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (textBox == null)
            return;

        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            PopulateHistoryList(textBox.Text);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void PopulateHistoryList(string text)
    {
        m_TextEntries.Add(text);
    }

    private event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
```

The above code will populate the TextEntries collection when the Enter Key is pressed on the textbox. I need two things

1. How do I set the Selected Item of the combo box and how can I bind that to my text box.
2. The combobox(dropmenu) should only show the last 10 entries from the drop down menu.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Using Expesssion Blend, binding the value of a property of one control to the property value of another control is easy, and it is known as ElementProperty Binding, here is a screenshot of where you access the ability to create this within Blend, note that the Textbox is the selected element in the Objects and Timeline panel, and it's the 'little box' to the right of the Text property in the properties panel which has been clicked to produce the context menu pictured...
[image]

Once you have selected 'Element Property Binding' for the text property of your textbox, your cursor will become a little bullseye icon, which you now will use to indicate what you want to bind to, by clicking it in either the design canvas or the Objects and Timeline panel, while the cursor appears that way...
[image]
Here we see the 'SelectedValue' property of the combo box being selected as the source of what is displayed in the textbox. Once done, the textbox will automagically be immediately set to display whatever is selected in the combo. Be sure to take a look at what Blend is doing in your XAML when you do this, as it will help you better understand what is actually going on, and might even teach you a thing or two about the binding syntax of XAML.
As for the list only ever having the last ten entries...there are several ways to do this, each one more or less appropriate, depending on the surrounding context, but here is one way; simply run a procedure similar to this one, whenever the box has entries added to it:

```
// assuming 'listItems' is your ObservableCollection
string[] items = listItems.ToArray();

// prepare a new array for the current ten
string[] tenItems = new string[10];

// copy a subset of length ten, to the temp array, the set your ObservableCollection to this array.
Array.Copy(items, (items.Length - 10), tenItems, 0, 10);
```

Note: The Array .Copy assumes the only way items are getting added to the observable collection is by some form of .Add, which always adds them to the end of the list...

Answer (score 0):

Part of the answer

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=cb, Path=SelectedValue}" />


<ComboBox x:Name="cb" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Fields}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedValue}"  />
```

And if you set the datacontext of the window

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}">
```